# File not found in TexMaker in Ubuntu

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I have a thesis paper, writing in Texmaker in Ubuntu. It was working fine and i have finished my work with `.bib` file for the references. But, suddenly it gives a `'file not found'` error when i try to compile it. I am trying hard to find out the problem. I tried to set the path for `pdflatex.exe` again. But, it is not solved. I can not find any clue what happened suddenly. Could anyone give me any hints please ?

Comment: Since you said that it was working I'll suppose that you already have TeXlive installed. So, can you open your `tex` file in TeXmaker? If yes, what happens when you press F6? If everything is right it should compile and crate the PDF file. Then, press F7 to view it. To rum BibTeX, press F11 (or F10, I don't remember).

Comment: Might also be an idea to let us know a bit more about your system. Like (1) are you using latex from ubuntu or from a manually installed TeX Live, (2) can you compile the file manually on the command line using `pdflatex`?, (3) if you used a manually installed TL and (2) is true, how did you add TL to the path?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.